# Difference between present perfect and present perfect continuous

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

What is the difference between the following 2 sentences? Or are they same?

1. He has walked for an hour.
2. He has been walking for an hour.

Is it that in 1, he may not walk now and in 2, he is walking now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One difference is that for #2 is certain the walking has been continuous for the last hour. With #1, one hour may be the total time spent walking in short segments over a longer period.